# How can I take Ubuntu Certification Exams online?

Tags: certification

How can I take Ubuntu Certification Exams online? No dates and no information about exams are specified on their website.

I want to take, at the very least, the exam in the course [Training: Deploying Ubuntu Server Edition](http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=481) ([archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20110322015326/http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=481)), but the information I want is not included on the page.

Comment: I send question today to ubuntu shop, but I still didn't get answer http://shop.canonical.com/enquiries.php?ID=26498&g=eab18a4022ff1be2291d228f810040a1

Comment: As Yosef mentioned - try http://shop.canonical.com/contact_us.php

Answer (score 3):

The best thing would be to contact Canonical via this [form link](https://forms.canonical.com/sales/)

They would be knowing better than any of the community members.

Comment: http://shop.canonical.com/contact_us.php